# i need so input with xml and webclient in wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, webclient

Is there anyway to read the specific line?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hDPIg.jpg

```
                XDocument dataFeed = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

                AchivementsListBox.ItemsSource = from query in dataFeed.Descendants("MaxPayne3")
                                                 select new NewGamesClass
                                                 {
                                                     GameGuide = (string)query.Element("Guide")

                                                 };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use a single `WebClient` instance to download the files, and simply reduce it to a single event handler. More than that, you have a similar document structure from  what I can tell. That means that you could also re-use your reading code instead of writing it twice.

Something like this:

```
void Download(GameType type, Action onCompletion)
{
    WebClient client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, args) =>
    {
        // Handle change in progress.
    };

    client.DownloadStringCompleted += (s, args) =>
    {
        XDocument feed = XDocument.Parse(args.Result);

        var itemSource = from query in feed.Root
                                      select new NewGamesClass
                                      {
                                          NewGameTitle = (string)query.Element("Title"),
                                          NewGameDescription = (string)query.Element("Descript
                                          NewGameImage = (string)query.Element("Image")
                                      };
        switch (type)
        {
            case GameType.ComingSoon:
                {
                    ComingSoonList.ItemSource = itemSource;
                }
            case GameType.NewGames:
                {
                    NewGameList.ItemSource = itemSource;
                }

        }

        if (onCompletion != null)
            onCompletion();
    };

    switch (type)
    {
        case GameType.NewGames:
            {
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://microsoft.com", UriKind.Absolute));
                break;
            }
        case GameType.ComingSoon:
            {
                client.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri("http://www.bing.com", UriKind.Absolute));
                break;
            }
    }
}
```

Although the code might look a bit more complex, it lets you recursively download data when a specific data set is downloaded. Obviously, you would have to declare the `GameType` enum and I simply used a bunch of test values here to demonstrate the idea.

Comment: But thing is he has values in listbox and he wants to get details on each tap or selection of list item. With your method it will send server calls on each click that is not really good approach.

Comment: Depends on the data he needs to operate with. From what I understand, he want to update it every time the user taps, so this method is more than acceptable.

Comment: Hi, I have installed your app. And navigated to that page but there is no link on that. Can you please share some piece of code or some sample application. So I can better help you. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
// It Will Download The XML Once To Use further to Avoid Again And Again Calls For Each Time


public void GetXML(string path)
            {
                WebClient wcXML = new WebClient();
                wcXML.OpenReadAsync(new Uri(path));
                wcXML.OpenReadCompleted += new OpenReadCompletedEventHandler(webClient);
            }

void webClient(object sender, OpenReadCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Error == null)
            {
                try
                {
                    Stream Resultstream = e.Result;
                    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(Resultstream);

                        var isolatedfile = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                        using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("Download.xml", System.IO.FileMode.Create, isolatedfile))
                        {
                            byte[] buffer = new byte[e.Result.Length];
                            while (e.Result.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
                            {
                                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            }
                            stream.Flush();
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(0);
                        }
                }

                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    //Log Exception
                }
            }

            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                //Log Exception
            }
        }

// This Method Will Give You Required Info According To Your Tag Like "Achievement123"

protected List<DownloadInfo> GetDetailFromXML(string TagName)
        {
            //TagName Like "achivement23"
            List<DownloadInfo> listDetails = new List<DownloadInfo>();

            XDocument loadedData;
            try
            {
                using (var storage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication())
                {
                    // Check For Islated Storage And Load From That
                    if (storage.FileExists("Download.xml"))
                    {
                        using (Stream stream = storage.OpenFile("Download.xml", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
                        {
                            loadedData = XDocument.Load(stream);
                            //TagName Like "achivement23"
                            listDetails.AddRange((from query in loadedData.Element("GOW1").Elements(TagName)
                                                  select new DownloadInfo
                                                  {
                                                      TITLE = (string)query.Element("TITLE"),
                                                      DESCRIPTION = (string)query.Element("DESCRIPTION"),
                                                      ACHIVEMENTIMAGE = (string)query.Element("ACHIVEMENTIMAGE"),
                                                      GUIDE = (string)query.Element("GUIDE"),
                                                      YOUTUBELINK = (string)query.Element("YOUTUBELINK")
                                                  }).ToList());
                        }
                    }
                }
                return listDetails;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return listDetails = null;
                //Log Exception
            }
        }

        public class DownloadInfo
        {
            public string TITLE { get; set; }
            public string DESCRIPTION { get; set; }
            public string GUIDE { get; set; }
            public string ACHIVEMENTIMAGE { get; set; }
            public string YOUTUBELINK { get; set; }
        }
```

Here is Your Method Calls

```
GetXML("ANY URL FROM WHERE YOU WANT TO GET XML"); // You Will Download All The XML Once To Avoid Again And Again Server Calls To Get XML. 

GetDetailFromXML("YOUR TAG NAME"); // It Will Take Your Tag Name Which Information You Want To Get Like "Acheicement123" and It Will Return You Data In List<DownloadInfo> and You can easily get data from this List.
```

I hope it will help you. I didnot Test The Code on Runtime. But I Hope It Will Give You Some Idea.. :)